Prove that $\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))=|\det A|\mathcal{L}^n(E)$
Suppose I  have a linear map $A:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$
I want to prove $\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))=|\det A|\mathcal{L}^n(E) $ $\forall E\subset \mathbb R^n$ where $\mathcal{L}^n$ is Lebesgue measure in $ \mathbb R^n$
My professor already proved the result, but there is a point that is not clear to me: in what follows I compare their and mine reasoning, using bold type character for the parts I'm unsure of.
Proof. Suppose $A$ is invertible  than if we define $\mu(E)=\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))$   we have $\mu(E+v)=\mu(E)$
and $\mu$ is regular in a topological sense  I mean that $\forall E \subset \mathbb R^n, \: \mu(E)= \inf \{\mu(A) : \: A \text{ is open } \}$   so $\mu(E)=c\mathcal{L}^n(E)$
My proof.  I thought he used the fact that Lebesgue measure is regular in a topological sense in this way  $\mu(E)=\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))= \inf \{ \mathcal{L}^n(A(O)) : \: \text{where } O \supset E \text{ and } O \text{ is open} \}= \inf \mu (O) $.
Could it be right ?

You need more details for that. You only know that $\mathcal{L}^n(A(E)) = \inf{\mathcal{L}^n(O) : A(E) \subset O, O\text{ is open}}$.

E a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

@stange ok... how should I continue ? any hints or something ?

@SamGinrich yes

@Dsrksidemath If $A(E) \subset O$ for some open set $O$, what can you say about $E$ in relation to $A^{-1}(O)$? ($A$ is supposed to be invertible). And, can you say something about the topological properties of $A^{-1}(O)$?

If $E$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, then either $E=\Bbb R^n$ and in this case $\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))= \mathcal{L}^n(E)= \infty$ or $E$ is a proper subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and in this case $\mathcal{L}^n(A(E))= \mathcal{L}^n(E)= 0$.

@stange         $A^-1(O)$   should be an open set (I don't know why , my professor said linear maps are open map ...) and $E \subset A^-1(O)$ so I have $ \mu(E)=\inf { \mathcal{L}^n((O)) : : \text{where } O \supset A(E) \text{ and } O \text{ is open} }= \inf { \mathcal{L}^n(O)) : : \text{where } A^-1(O) \supset E \text{ and } A^-1(O) \text{ is open} } =\inf { \mu(A^-1(O)) : : \text{where } A^-1(O) \supset E \text{ and } A^-1(O) \text{ is open} }  $  is it right ?

edit : linear maps are always open if they are surjective is it a theorem I didn't know , and this is the case bacause $A$ is invertible

@Dsrksidemath Looks ok to me.
